# how to replicate bootstrap close alert functionality?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

My manager has asked me to replicate the bootstrap alert functionality.  He basically wants to keep the file contents minimal.  I've been able to replicate the alert display but I'm not clear on how to replicate the close functionality in my local implementation. My preference is to use keep my local code as close as possible to the bootstrap implementation. Do you know how bootstrap wires up the close button for alerts and if I can easily copy this implementation down into my local implementation?

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on what you have available. I'll assume you're going to stick to vanilla CSS and JS. In such a case you could do something like the following:

```js
var alert = document.getElementsByClassName('alert')[0];

var closeButton = document.getElementsByClassName('alert-close')[0];
closeButton.onclick = function() {
  alert.style.opacity = 0;
}
```

```css
.alert {
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.4s;
}
.alert-header {
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
}
.alert-close {
  float: right;
}
.alert-content {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
  <div class="alert-header">
    <strong>Alert title</strong>
    <button class="alert-close">x</button>
  </div>
  <div class="alert-content">
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor amet pork jerky tenderloin beef ribs. Meatball pork belly short ribs pastrami. Ball tip pastrami venison brisket jerky filet mignon meatloaf flank picanha pork loin chicken salami beef. Jerky chicken t-bone, tenderloin beef ribs sirloin
      pork belly beef rump kielbasa salami flank sausage ground round. Cow swine shank filet mignon fatback strip steak, salami tenderloin frankfurter flank.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note that the JS element selectors should be more refined to suit your needs, especially if you have more than one alert per page.

If you need to make any kind of complex selections in JS then I highly recommend jQuery.

Comment: thanks jens.  do you know how to achieve the fade effect onclose that happens with the bootstrap alerts?

Comment: @user6604655 I edited my answer to add a basic fade effect on the alert. It simply uses CSS transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to **jens1101** answer.

> do you know how to achieve the fade effect onclose that happens with the bootstrap alerts?

`transition: visibility 0s 1s, opacity 0.3s linear;` Will do the trick.

```js
var alert = document.getElementsByClassName('alert')[0];

var closeButton = document.getElementsByClassName('alert-close')[0];
closeButton.onclick = function() {
    
    
 alert.style.opacity = 0;

}
```

```css
.alert {
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: visibility 0s 1s, opacity 0.3s linear;
}

.alert-header {
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
}

.alert-close {
  float: right;
}

.alert-content {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
  <div class="alert-header">
    <strong>Alert title</strong>
    <button class="alert-close">x</button>
  </div>
  <div class="alert-content">
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor amet pork jerky tenderloin beef ribs. Meatball pork belly short ribs pastrami. Ball tip pastrami venison brisket jerky filet mignon meatloaf flank picanha pork loin chicken salami beef. Jerky chicken t-bone, tenderloin beef ribs sirloin
      pork belly beef rump kielbasa salami flank sausage ground round. Cow swine shank filet mignon fatback strip steak, salami tenderloin frankfurter flank.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```